# External connection to Synology NAS stopped working

Tags: networking, router, portforwarding, modem, synology

I had my Synology NAS all set up until recently to allow me remote access.

Last week my broadband company 'upgraded' my Router and sent me their new 'Virgin Hub'.

Ever since then I cannot port forward into my NAS even though I have an IP4 address and have set up port forwards AND confirmed they are open.

This is my Setup and I had a couple of questions.

1. On the previous working I can't recall if the Router A should be attached to WIFI Point B via the WAN port or the regular ETH port?
2. On previous setup, I have a feeling that WIFI Port B was actually on a subnet of 192.168.1.1 instead

Any tips appreciated

[image]

Comment: What are the first two octets of your new public IPv4 address?

Comment: Do you mean the first 2 clusters of numbers? it's
188.141.XX.XXX